# Some location based mobile sites not working in chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, permissions, geolocation

I'm getting a message from some websites (m.yelp.com and nextbus.com) they do not have "permission to access your location". I have my location permission turned on for chrome in the app manager and set to "ask first" in the site settings tab of the chrome settings. These sites are not blocked in site settings.

The location works fine on some sites, ie maps.google.com. I get a message asking if I want to give my location information and once I approve it works.

Am i missing something, is there somewhere else I need to grant permission? Is anyone else seeing this?

I'm running marshmallow on an htc m8.

Comment: Does this happen with an another browser as well, such as Firefox?

Comment: @Firelord, Firefox seems to be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that starting with the April release of chrome for android, only sites using https can request location information.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en